# App Crashes throwing an exception of permission denial:reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am developing an app which needs permission to read and write External Storage.i have write all the permissions in Manifest file as well as also in my java activity file but my app still got crashed as soon as it starts 
 with throwing an Exception of

`permission denial:reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider`

> Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abhi.scrolling_tab">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Fragment_one"
        android:label="Fragment_one"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Fragment_two"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_two"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Fragment_three"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_three"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

> Java File

```
public class Fragment_two extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView2;
private List<Model1> modelList;
private myAdapter2 adapter;
private MenuItem menu;


public Fragment_two() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_two, container, false);
    ;
    recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle2);
    int No_of_coloumns = 3;
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), No_of_coloumns));
    modelList = getAllaudiofromdevice();
    adapter = new myAdapter2(modelList, (ViewGroup) view);
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

public List<Model1> getAllaudiofromdevice() {
    List<Model1> files = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST};
        Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Model1 model1 = new Model1();
                String path = c.getString(0);
                String album = c.getString(1);
                String artist = c.getString(2);
                String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                model1.setName(name);
                model1.setArtist(artist);
                model1.setAlbum(album);
                model1.setPath(path);
                files.add(model1);
            }
            c.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    check();
    return files;
}

public void check() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        getAllaudiofromdevice();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestcode) {
        case 123:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getAllaudiofromdevice();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "you have to set permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                check();
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestcode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

}

Please help me to get out of this.
Thanks in the anticipation.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your entire Java stack trace.

Comment: Looks like you granted `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime, but not reading, according to the error

Comment: @cricket_007 When asking any permission from a permission group you'll be granted all permissions from that group. It's how it worked so far since Marshmallow. See permission groups here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply sir @CommonsWare but the same code is working now.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Your code will run after giving permission because you are doing this in wrong order. You must call check() method, before getAllaudiofromdevice(); method. But you are calling it into getAllaudiofromdevice();

Answer (score 0):

Only do work when the permission *is* granted. Your code contains a logical error:

```
if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // Mistake here.
    getAllaudiofromdevice();
} //...
```

Also on API 23 your code will request permissions when they're not granted, but will do nothing(*) when they already are granted. It should be like this:

```
public void check() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Request permissions if they're not granted on API 23.
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
    } else {
        // Do work on API <23 and when permissions were granted on API 23+.
        getAllaudiofromdevice();
    }
}
```

(*) Depending on how you call your code, it's really confusing.